# error with apt-get and dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg

I cannot do any apt-get commands without error. I have tried many commands like `sudo apt-get purge`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo dpkg --configure` `initramfs-tools`, etc.

I continue to get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.19.0-23-generic (3.19.0-23.24) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-23-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-23-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-23-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.19.0-23-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-23-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.19.0.23.22); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                       Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-23-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
scott@scott-1015E:/$
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Instead of apologising for the bad formatting, why can't you fix it? For more information on formatting please read: http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: possible duplicate of ["gzip: stdout: No space left on device"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308793/gzip-stdout-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: because what I pasted was exactly what appeared in my terminal making MY eyes spin, if I knew how to fix anything I would not have asked for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: Cleaning old files did fix the problem but I could not solve it in the terminal, which is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your /boot partition is full, apt-get tries to finish the installation of a new kernel from a previous upgrade but always fails due to lack of space, note the line `3 not fully installed or removed.`

I'd suggest to uninstall older versions of linux-image, but since that doesn't seem to be an option, try expanding your boot partition first.

Comment: Cleaning old files did fix the problem but I could not solve it in the terminal, which is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In desperation, I looked at what I had installed - I found Ubuntu Tweak so ran through the clean routines there. It worked where nothing I could find here did, so problem is solved.

Thank you to those who tried to help.

Comment: Cleaning old files did fix the problem but I could not solve it in the terminal, which is what I was trying to do.